# Estimating P(X $\ge$ k) with Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have managed to derive non-rigorously that

P(|X - E[X]| $\ge$ a) $\le$ $\frac{E[X - E[X]|^2}{a^2}$. for a random variable X.

Now let X be a random variable with Poisson distribution, with mean and variance equal to $\lambda$. 
I am supposed to use this inequality to place an estimate on P(X $\ge$ k) where k $\ge$ 0.

Initially I tried to do this by noting that P(X $\ge$ k) = 1 - P(X < k) = 1 - P(0 $\le$ X < k) and then writing this as an inequality, but this hasn't led anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Chebyshev's inequality will be useful if $k \gg \lambda = E(X)$. In this case, you can write
$$
P(x \ge k) = P(X -\lambda \ge k-\lambda)\le \frac{E(X - \lambda)^2}{(k-\lambda^2)} = \frac{\lambda}{(k-\lambda)^2}, 
$$
which gives something nontrivial if $k \gg \lambda.$ If $k $ is much smaller than $\lambda$ then its not possible to get an upper bound which is useful. For example if $k=0$ then $P(X \ge 0) =1$. It would be helpful to know what kind of estimate you want exactly to give a more precise answer.

Comment: Personally, I like your answer. I had already struck upon the exact same thing. However, my question makes no assumption about the value for k, and it's always a bold thinking to question whether the professor has made an error. I'll send her an email noting that in order to use Chebyshev's inequality we require k >> $\lambda$. Hopefully it's she who made an error and not the two of us.

Comment: Notice that I never mentioned we cannot use Chebyshev. We can use Chebyshev for any value of $k$, but it only gives something useful when $k \gg \lambda$.

Comment: You can't use Chebyshev if k - $\lambda$ < 0. Chebyshev requires that a > 0.

Comment: Yes sorry you are right, I was confusing this with Markov's inequality. Anyway, my point was you can use Chebyshev even when $x>\lambda$ but close to $\lambda$.

Answer (score -2):

You want a more general inequality: $P(|X|\geq a)\leq E[|X|]/a$ or $P(|X|^k\geq a^k)\leq E[|X|^k]/a^k$. Chebyshev's inequality is a consequence of this.

Comment: The first part of the question asked me to estimate using the inequality you suggested. The second part was exactly as I stated, using the Chebyshev inequality. If you can modify your answer, I'll bump you to +1.